# Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files?

Tags: mongodb

I have run mongorestore thousands of times and now of a sudden I get "Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files"

What on earth does it mean and what do I do about it?

[image: ""]

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8480).

> On Windows platforms code was previously added to zero-fill each newly
>   allocated data file in order to work around an issue described in this
>   Windows Knowledge Base article.

Take a look at [this thread](http://mongodb.2344371.n4.nabble.com/mongod-don-t-start-after-server-crash-td1096.html), which looks like has an answer. I can not test it because I do not have windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Mongodb lately? if so you need to create a folder in this address:

`C:\data\db`

This is the default address you can change it.